# Theming with ABS and HoloEverywhere

Tags: android, android-listview, actionbarsherlock, android-menu, android-holo-everywhere

I'm using `HoloEverywhere` and `ActionbarSherlock` to create my application. I've been successful in theming the `listview` i have in my main activity so that the color is grey instead of holo blue whenever pressed or focused. I would like to theme the preference options I have in a `PreferenceActivity` as well, but it only works for devices with pre-ICS. With devices running android 4.0+, whenever the option is pressed or focused, the color is still ICS blue.

Another question: I'm using a theme that's parent is `Holo.Theme.Light.DarkActionBar`. How would I make it so that it uses a light overflow popupmenu instead of the dark one? I've tried adding `popupmenustyle` to my styles, but I've had no luck

**styles.xml:**

```
    <style name="Theme" parent="Holo.Theme.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background</item>
        <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background</item>
        <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/activated_background_holo_light</item>
        <item name="activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/activated_background_holo_light</item>
        <item name="android:listChoiceBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/list_selector_holo_light</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">#666666</item>
        <item name="android:icon">@drawable/icon</item>
        <item name="background">#666666</item>
        <item name="icon">@drawable/icon</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this works:

```
<item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Intellistats</item>
<item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Intellistats</item>
```

where:

```
<style name="PopupMenu.Intellistats" parent="@style/Holo.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/holo_orange_dark</item>
</style>
```